# Melhor forma de aplicar um pattern para a sigla

Tags: javascript, regex

Tenho os seguintes retornos possíveis:

- AB
- A1
- A

O primeiro sempre será uma letra, o segundo poderá ocorrer ou não e poderá ser letra ou número. Em JavaScript está assim (Exemplo):

```
if (/^[A-Z][\w]$/.test(value.toUpperCase())) {
    callback(true)
} else if(/^[A-Z]$/.test(value.toUpperCase())) {
    callback(true)
} else {
    callback(false)
}
```

Gostaria de realizar a validação em apenas um `if`.

Comment: Ana, vc disse claramente que o primeiro caractere é sempre uma letra, ok. E no segundo caractere, pode vir qualquer caractere, exemplo: `!#$@%&*_-`?

Comment: @sam as opções para a segunda casa apenas serão: não vir nada, uma letra ou número.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A regex a seguir resolve seu problema de forma simples e sem criar grupos desnecessários.

```
/^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]?$/
```

Explicação:

- `^` indica que a ocorrência deve ser no início da string, senão a regex casaria com `xxxA2`;
- `[A-Z]`: um caractere entre A e Z
- `[A-Z0-9]?` um caractere entre A e Z ou entre 0 e 9, sendo este caractere opcional (ocorre 0 ou 1 vez)
- `$` indica que a ocorrência deve ser no fim da string, senão a regex casaria com `A2xxx`;

Exemplo:

```js
var regex = /^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]?$/;

// Válidos
console.log("A:", regex.test("A"));
console.log("A1:", regex.test("A1"));
console.log("AB:", regex.test("AB"));

// Inválidos
console.log("1:", regex.test("1"));
console.log("A1 :", regex.test("A1 "));
console.log("A-:", regex.test("A-"));
```

Comment: Considerei sua alternativa correta por ser mais simples de entender visualmente que as outras alternativas.

Comment: Como comentei nas outras respostas, elas são boas também, mas casam com algumas exceções que você não quer.

Comment: Sim. Isso também impactou na minha resposta.

Answer (score 3):

Esse Regex deve atender:

`/^[A-Z]([A-Z]*|\d+)$/`

```js
// validos
console.log(/^[A-Z]([A-Z]*|\d+)$/.test("A"))
console.log(/^[A-Z]([A-Z]*|\d+)$/.test("AB"))
console.log(/^[A-Z]([A-Z]*|\d+)$/.test("A1"))

//inválidos
console.log(/^[A-Z]([A-Z]*|\d+)$/.test("A-"))
console.log(/^[A-Z]([A-Z]*|\d+)$/.test("A@"))
console.log(/^[A-Z]([A-Z]*|\d+)$/.test("@1"))
console.log(/^[A-Z]([A-Z]*|\d+)$/.test("1A"))
```

Comment: O problema é que essa regex também vai casar com valores como `A123456` ou `ABCDEFGHI`. Pelo que o AP explicou só é válido se tiver 1 ou 2 caracteres.

Comment: O problema é o `*`... ele permite 0 ou mais repetição.. nesse caso seria apenas 0 ou 1 repetições.. que é o que o `?` faz. O `+` também é um problema pois permite 1 ou mais repetições e cai na mesma situação do `*`

Comment: pode então limitar o tamanho: `/^([A-Z]){0,1}([A-Z]|\d]*)$/`

Comment: modificando a sua regex seria algo como `/^[A-Z]([A-Z]|\d]){0,1}$/`. pois o segundo caracter é opcional.

Comment: Só lembrando que `{0,1}` pode ser trocado por `?`: https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html

Answer (score 3):

Esta regex também pode lhe atender:

```
/^[a-z][a-z\d]?$/i
```

A flag `i` irá dispensar o uso do método `.toUpperCase()`, pois irá ignorar se a letra for maiúscula ou minúscula.

Explicação:

```
[a-z]     O primeiro caractere é obrigatório ser uma letra
[a-z\d]  O segundo caractere é opcional, mas se existir
          deverá ser uma letra [a-z] ou um número \d
```

O `?` faz com que o `[a-z\d]` seja opcional. O `^` e o `$` delimitam a string a no máximo 2 caracteres à partir do primeiro.

Então o `if` ficaria:

```
if(/^[a-z][a-z\d]?$/i.test(value)){
   callback(true);
}else{
   callback(false);
}
```

**Teste:**

```js
function valida(i){
   if(/^[a-z][a-z\d]?$/i.test(i)){
      callback(true, i);
   }else{
      callback(false, i);
   }
}

function callback(x, i){
   console.clear();
   console.log("'"+ i +"' é "+ x);
}
```

```html
<p>Clique nos botões</p>
<button onclick="valida('a')">a</button>
<button onclick="valida('A')">A</button>
<button onclick="valida('aB')">aB</button>
<button onclick="valida('a#')">a#</button>
<button onclick="valida('a1')">a1</button>
<button onclick="valida('3A')">3A</button>
```